# How many objects are created by using the Integer wrapper class?

Tags: java, integer, wrapper

```
Integer i = 3; 
i = i + 1; 
Integer j = i; 
j = i + j;
```

How many objects are created as a result of the statements in the sample code above and why? Is there any IDE in which we can see how many objects are created (maybe in a debug mode)?

Comment: AFAIK, any decent IDE with CPU and/or memory profiler should do; NetBeans comes to mind. Just execute profiling (note to enable profiling standard lib classes too!) and look at a) how many Integer object were created (by looking at the memory used etc. in memory profiler), b) how many times the Integer c-tor was called (by looking at the method execution counts in CPU profiler)

Answer (score 101, accepted):

The answer, surprisingly, is zero.

All the `Integer`s from -128 to +127 are pre-computed by the JVM.

Your code creates *references* to these *existing* objects.

Comment: See [Write a program that makes 2 + 2 = 5](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/28818/15968) for an example of how to access these existing objects (you **really** shouldn't) and manipulate them for comic/disastrous effect (you **really really** shouldn't).

Comment: @MT0 Thanks guys. I love you both.Is there any reference link for it?

Comment: @SyameshK https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf(int) "This method will always cache values in the range -128 to 127, inclusive, and may cache other values outside of this range."

Comment: Is this specific to Oracle Java or must this be true for other implementations (like IBM) also?

Comment: @MartinSchröder it is required by the Java language specification https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7

Comment: @josefx: But: "The implementation *may* cache these, lazily or eagerly." (emphasis mine)

Comment: Does this goes with java5 as well?

Answer (score 60):

The strictly correct answer is that the number of `Integer` objects created is *indeterminate*.  It could be between 0 and 3, or 256<sup>1</sup> or even more<sup>2</sup>, depending on

- the Java platform<sup>3</sup>,
- whether this is the first time that this code is executed, and
- (potentially) whether other code that relies on boxing of `int` values runs before it<sup>4</sup>.

The `Integer` values for -128 to 127 are not strictly required to be *precomputed*.  In fact, [JLS 5.1.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7) which specified the Boxing conversion says this:

> If the value p being boxed is an integer literal of type int between -128 and 127 inclusive (§3.10.1) ... then let a and b be the results of any two boxing conversions of p. It is always the case that a == b.

Two things to note:

- The JLS only *requires* this for >>literals<<.
- The JLS does not mandate *eager* caching of the values.  Lazy caching also satisfies the JLS's behavioral requirements.

Even the javadoc for `Integer.valueof(int)` does not *specify* that the results are cached eagerly.

If we examine the Java SE source code for `java.lang.Integer` from Java 6 through 8, it is clear that the current Java SE implementation strategy is to precompute the values.  However, for various reasons (see above) that is still not enough to allow us to give a definite answer to the "how many objects" question.

---

<sup>1 - It could be 256 if execution of the above code triggers class initialization for `Integer` in a version of Java where the cache is eagerly initialized during class initialization.</sup>

<sup>2 - It could be even more, if the cache is larger than the JVM spec requires.  The cache size can be increased via a JVM option in some versions of Java.</sup>

<sup>3 - In addition to the platform's general approach to implementing boxing, a compiler could spot that some or all of the computation could be done at compile time or optimized it away entirely.</sup>

<sup>4 - Such code could trigger either lazy or eager initialization of the integer cache.</sup>

Comment: This is not the complete story. These `Integer` objects are precomputed in the class initializer of `java.lang.Integer.IntegerCache` but the initialization of that class is triggered by its first use so unless the JRE uses such boxed values itself before entering the `main` method (in my test it didn’t), the first boxing of a value inside that range will trigger the initialization. So it’s not correct to say that no `Integer` objects are created as in fact 256 `Integer` objects are created while executing the `main` method.

Comment: @Holger - It is also not correct to say that the number is not zero because 1) we don't >>know<< that this code is in the main method, and 2) we don't >>know<< that the actual JVM implements the cache the same way as Java 6 through 8.  Also, the number could be LARGER than 256.

Comment: Indeed, things can get even more complicated. I was specifically referring to the last part about the “current generation Oracle & OpenJDK Java SE JVMs”. As said in the comment that has been removed, HotSpot may also remove the boxing as it knows about it’s semantics and the question’s code does not depend on the identities of the `Integer` objects. Or it may elide the entire operation, if `i` and `j` are never used afterwards. A different JVM implementation could represent certain boxed values by storing `int` values inside of pointers to address ranges outside the heap without any objects…

Comment: @Holger - It is theoretically possible that boxed values could be outside of the heap ... but implausible.  Dealing with that possibility for every reference would an unwarranted GC overhead.

Comment: The overhead wouldn’t be necessarily big. E.g., the current 32 Bit JVMs don’t support heaps larger than 2GB, which implies that the highest bit of in-heap addresses is never set. So if off-heap references always have that bit set, you can easily test it, as it is identical to the sign bit and almost every CPU has an intrinsic test for it, most of them provide it even for free when loading the address into a CPU register. So you can combine the off-heap test with the `null` reference test, which you need anyway (if `>0` traverse, otherwise it’s either `null` or off-heap)…

Comment: The 31 bit limitation on heap size is only for 32bit Windows.  For 32 bit Linux, the there are 3GB of virtual address space that is usable.  And many people / applications use a 64 bit JVM.  Besides, the concrete benefit of holding (say) a couple of hundred boxed values outside of the heap is ... minimal.

Comment: In the past, all memory with the highest bit set was dedicated kernel space, hence unusable for user code. Today, this has been lifted for 32Bit processes, but for compatibility reasons, the heap still has to reside in the lower 2GB space, that’s exactly the reason why 32Bit JVMs still can’t use more than 2GB for the heap, despite the most recent operating systems support up to 3GB user space. This applies to both, Windows and Linux, both os support 3GB user space, but Oracle’s 32 Bit JVMs don’t support heap sizes `>2GB`.

Comment: *"On 64-bit operating systems running the 32-bit VM, the max heap size can be higher, approaching 4G on many Solaris systems."* - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/hotspotfaq-138619.html#gc_heap_32bit

Comment: In short, 32 bit Oracle JVMs on 64 bit platforms do support > 2G heaps, depending on the OS.

Comment: Let’s end with the conclusion that not every JVM would benefit from such an optimization, but that never was the premise. A 32 bit JVM that restricts *its heap* to the lower 2GB might use such a trick and the potentially saving of up to 2³¹ boxed values (which would otherwise consume up to 16GB of memory, considering the minimum object size of 8 bytes), could justify not using the other 1GB of memory *for the heap*. Note that this memory area still might hold non-heap resources like I/O buffers and the metaspace. And on a lot of system’s, native code lies in the same address space as the data.

Answer (score 17):

First of all: The answer you are looking for is `0`, as others already mentioned.

But let's go a bit deeper. As Stephen menthioned it depends on the time you execute it. Because the cache is actually lazy initialized.

If you look at the documentation of java.lang.Integer.IntegerCache:

> The cache is initialized on first usage.

This means that if it is the first time you call any Integer you actually create:

- 256 Integer Objects (or more: see below)
- 1 Object for the Array to store the Integers
- Let's ignore the Objects needed for Store the Class (and Methods / Fields). They are anyway stored in the metaspace.

From the second time on you call them, you create 0 Objects.

---

Things get more funny once you make the numbers a bit higher. E.g. by the following example:

```
Integer i = 1500;
```

Valid options here are: 0, 1 or any number between 1629 to 2147483776 (this time only counting the created Integer-values.
Why? The answer is given in the next sentence of Integer-Cache definition:

> The size of the cache may be controlled by the -XX:AutoBoxCacheMax= option.

So you actually can vary the size of the cache which is implemented.

Which means you can reach for above line:

- 1: new Object if your cache is smaller than 1500
- 0: new Objects if your cache has been initialized before and contains 1500
- 1629: new (Integer) - Objects if your cache is set to exactly 1500 and has not been initialized yet. Then Integer-values from -128 to 1500 will be created.
- As in the sentence above you reach any amount of integer Objects here up to: Integer.MAX_VALUE + 129, which is the mentioned: 2147483776.

**Keep in mind:** This is only guaranteed on Oracle / Open JDK (i checked Version 7 and 8)

As you can see the completely correct answer is not so easy to get. But just saying `0` will make people happy.

---

PS: using the menthoned parameter can make the following statement true: `Integer.valueOf(1500) == 1500`

Answer (score 5):

The compiler unboxes the `Integer` objects to `int`s to do arithmetic with them by calling [`intValue()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#intValue--) on them, and it calls [`Integer.valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf-int-) to box the `int` results when they are assigned to `Integer` variables, so your example is equivalent to:

```
Integer i = Integer.valueOf(3);
i = Integer.valueOf(i.intValue() + 1);
Integer j = i;
j = Integer.valueOf(i.intValue() + j.intValue());
```

The assignment `j = i;` is a completely normal object reference assignment which creates no new objects. It does no boxing or unboxing, and doesn't need to as `Integer` objects are immutable.

The `valueOf` method is allowed to cache objects and return the same instance each time for a particular number. It is *required* to cache ints −128 through +127. For your starting number of `i = 3`, all the numbers are small and guaranteed to be cached, so the number of objects that need to be created is **0**. Strictly speaking, `valueOf` is allowed to cache instances lazily rather than having them all pre-generated, so the example might still create objects the first time, but if the code is run repeatedly during a program the number of objects created each time *on average* approaches 0.

What if you start with a larger number whose instances will not be cached (e.g., `i = 300`)? Then each `valueOf` call must create one new `Integer` object, and the total number of objects created each time is **3**.

(*Or*, maybe it's still zero, or maybe it's millions. Remember that compilers and virtual machines are allowed to rewrite code for performance or implementation reasons, so long as its behavior is not otherwise changed. So it could delete the above code entirely if you don't *use* the result. Or if you try to print `j`, it could realize that `j` will always end up with the same constant value after the above snippet, and thus do all the arithmetic at compile time, and print a constant value. The actual amount of work done behind the scenes to run your code is always an implementation detail.)

Answer (score 2):

You can debug the Integer.valueOf(int i) method to find out it by yourself.
This method is called by the autoboxing process by the compiler.

Comment: This is not a good approach to finding the answer.  It only tells you what happens on a specific execution platform.  Other platforms could give you different results.